# reading other file's constants/variables from php class

Tags: php, class, oop

I am fairly new to php oop and some concepts are still new to me.

Asumming I have a config file (config.php) that consist of:

```
<?php

$siteName  = "John's Site";
$siteEmail = "john@johnnysample.com"
$replyTo   = "support@johnnysample.com"
```

And I have a simple class (SendMail.php) that consists of:

```
class SendMail
{

    public function sendRegistrationMail($toAddress)
    {
        mail($toAddress, $subject, $email, "From: Site Name <sample@example.com>");

    }

}
```

And I have the user.php file that consists of:

```
<?php
include_once ('config.php');
include_once ('SendMail.php);

//Initialize class
$sendMail = new SendMail();
```

What I'm asking is if I could somehow read/include config.php from
SendMail Class so that I can simply do this:

```
$sendMail->sendRegistrationMail("registered@useraddress.com");
```

without the need to pass the "From:" address when sending the email
and without the need to hardcode `"From: Site Name <sample@example.com>"`
as I have done.

Hope I was clear.
If anyone could help out that would be awesome.
Thank you!

Comment: There aren't any [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) defined here at all.... if you mean variables, then read about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your config file being normal runnable PHP, you can just reference the global variables in your SendMail class like this:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';

class SendMail
{
    public function sendRegistrationMail($toAddress)
    {
        global $siteName, $siteEmail, replyTo;
        mail($toAddress, $subject, $email, "From: {$siteName} <{$replyTo}>");
    }

}
```

Since the variables in your config are PHP and they are defined in the global scope, including the file will make them accessible here.  You just need to specify in the function that the variables you are referencing are the globally scoped ones, not new local variables which is what the global keyword does.

Comment: Thanks. Is this considered a good practice? I've read somewhere that
global variables arent a good practice? Should I stick with specifying a the "From: " address  as a parameter or do this instead?

Comment: In general, global variables are bad practice because it's easy for other parts of the program to muck around with them unseen to you.  For config files, I usually allow an exception to the no globals rule since they tend to be read only and needed in lots of places.  You can make your code a little cleaner/clearer though by scoping them to a class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use class variables to specify a lists of possible data.
Or you could create method which will include your config file.
Or you can add a second argument to method in a string form.

Comment: I dont want to re-specify the email address in a class variable I want to have it all in one file.
I specified that I'm not trying to do it with a second argument either.

So If I create a method to read config, the config.php variables will be readable from inside the SendMail class?